# How to find the parameter key from window location path?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, window.location

I have query string is as follows.

Window.location.href = `http://192.168.1.25:9990/myprofile?IkNBMTEyOTA4MjYyOSI.5sTmOAZU-ZNmqDpVIx4SnLjzsMs`

I am trying window.location.search I am getting `?IkNBMTEyOTA4MjYyOSI.5sTmOAZU-ZNmqDpVIx4SnLjzsMs`

But expected output : `IkNBMTEyOTA4MjYyOSI.5sTmOAZU-ZNmqDpVIx4SnLjzsMs` I need without `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
window.location.search.substring(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `searchParams.get()` like this example :

```
var currentUrl = Window.location.href;
var url = new URL(currentUrl);
var c = url.searchParams.get("myprofile");
```

Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams#Example)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var urlStr = "http://192.168.1.25:9990/myprofile?IkNBMTEyOTA4MjYyOSI.5sTmOAZU-ZNmqDpVIx4SnLjzsMs";

function getqueryString(url) {
  var retObj = {};
  if (!url) return retObj;

  var str = url.split('?')[1];

  if (!str) return retObj;


  var query = str.split('&');

  for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {

    var pair = query[i].split('=');

    retObj[pair[0]] = pair[1];

  }

  return retObj;

}

var rsl = getqueryString(urlStr);
console.log(rsl)
```

You can use this function it takes URL as the parameter and returns Back all the query parameter in an object form